# Conditional type property on generic class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, deno

why does this not work??

```js
export class Client<isReady extends boolean = false> {
  user: isReady extends true ? ClientUser : null = null
}
```

Deno throws this error `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'isReady extends true ? ClientUser : null'.deno-ts(2322)`
on the user property

I want the `user` property to be only of type `null` at some places and only of type `ClientUser` at some places and I also want it to be initialized with the value as `null`.

Comment: You can use [`user: ClientUser | null = null;`](https://tsplay.dev/W48BaW) without any problems.

Comment: i did that but then where i know that the `user` property will not be null i have to do useless null checks and i dont want to do `user!` either, i try to avoid non-null assertions so i want it to be only `ClientUser` there

Comment: In order to cleanly assign to `user`, the interface of the object assigned to it must satisfy both `ClientUser` **and** `null`. Clearly, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `!` operator as suffix of `user`:

```js
export class Client {
  user!: ClientUser
}
```

But I do not recommend this because you will lose typescript checks.

It is better to use `ClientUser | null` union, you need the do some null check, but you will keep your code type safe.